# CSS rotating causes change in size of clip image

Tags: css, html, safari, webkit

**What:** I am attempting to make a UI for a project. I wanted to have several small white rectangle over an image and be able to rotate the rectangles to create a horizontal blinds effect. All went well in chrome but when I explored how it looked in safari I was hit with some confusion.

**Code snippet:**

```
<figure id="blinds-window">
<img src=full/beach.jpg  usemap="#map" alt class=first>
<img src=full/white.jpg usemap="#map" alt class=second>
<img src=full/white.jpg usemap="#map" alt class=second>
```

To rotate create the clip I'm using the following

```
figure img.second { transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(1px); }
figure img:nth-child(2) { 
clip: rect(0px, 640px, 50px, 0px);
transform-origin: 320px 25px;
}
figure img:nth-child(3) {
clip: rect(50px, 640px, 100px, 0px);
transform-origin: 320px 75px;
```

**Problem:** In safari the rectangle clip is shortened to less then half of its size unless its at rotationX=0deg.

Any help would be great.

**What have I tried:** Well the position is set to absolute which was all I really knew to check in this case. I am at a lost what could cause this behavior.

**Example:**
See the image below set to 10 degrees.

[image]

And here when set to 0 degrees.
[image]

**Note:** That even when set to 2 degrees the clip still remains less then half its size.

Comment: Did anyone get the bounty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally i would go with a much simpler approach, and not use any kind of rotations and/ or transform.
If all you want to achieve is the "blinds" effect, I would go with just animating the height of the rectangles, and enjoy a much wider support, and less vendor-specific css...

Check it here: <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/YTycg/8/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400&text=Your Image Here" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="toggle" value="hide" />
```

**CSS**

```
div.line {position:absolute;width:100%;background-color:white;transition:height 1.5s;}
#container.show div.line {height:10%;}
#container.hide div.line {height:0%;}
```

**JS**

```
var container = $('#container');
var numberOfLines = 10;

var coverImage = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
        container.append('<div class="line"></div>');
    }
    var lines = $('.line', container);
    var imageHeight = $('img', container).outerHeight();
    var lineHeight = imageHeight/lines.length;

    lines.each(function(i){
        $(this).css({ top: i*lineHeight });
    });
    container.addClass('hide');
};
coverImage();

$('#toggle').click(function(){
    container.toggleClass('show hide');
    $(this).val(container.attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: Love your simple solution! I went the route at first due to needing to set the blinds to incremental positions. So in your code i would need to be able to set the heights of your rectangles not just simply transition from open blinds to closed but in between positions. +1 though for the simple solution.

Comment: Thanks!
You can leave the positioning as is, and just animate the height not from 0 to lineHeight, but instead to any number in between these two values to get the "half open" effect.
BTW, if it solved your problem, can you please mark it as the right answer? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can't understand, why would you like to use `clip`.

If I were, I would do it that way: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/y9bQv/

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://waldorfastoria3.hilton.com/resources/media/wa/EYWRRWA/en_US/img/shared/full_page_image_gallery/main/WA_beach_8.jpg"
    />
    <div class="blinds">
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
        <div class="blind"></div>
    </div>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.blinds {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.blind {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: blind 5s both infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blind {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    }
}
```

It will work only in WebKit browsers, if need more, please, add more prefixed attributes.

Comment: The reason I went this way is due to wanting a more realistic look. Note in the images you can actually see the edge of the blinds sticking over the edge of the photo giving it a perspective look. Yes, looking back it seems like to much attention to detail, but it does look very realistic. Im happier with a simpler approach tough and thus and switching now.